# Exactly same Python Program when tested in "Run Code" and "Submit" gives two different outputs on LeetCode

Tags: python, algorithm

I wrote the following solution for the [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/climbing-stairs/) on LeetCode. This question isn't about how to solve the given problem but, the discrepancy/glitch/bug or something else in the testing system on LeetCode.

My **solution works perfectly** for the test code on the input of **n=3** when I use the **"Run Code" button** to test it and it outputs **ways=3** (same as the expected answer of **ways=3**).

But, if I use the **"Submit" button** to test the **exact same code** the solution is **denied(i.e. rejected)** since it outputs **ways=2** (different from the expected **ways=3**).

**Question Overview:** There is a staircase of n-steps. A person can either climb 2 or 1 steps at a time. How many distinct ways are there to climb the stairs?

**My Program:**

```
class Solution:
    t = 0
    D = {}
    def climbStairs(self, n: int) -> int:
        return self.rec_func(n, 0)
        
    def rec_func(self, n, current):
        
        
        if current in self.D.keys():
            return self.D[current]
        # print(current, self.t, n-current)
        if n==current:
            return 1
        
        if n < current:
            return 0
        
        ans = (self.rec_func(n, current+1) + self.rec_func(n, current+2))
        self.D[current]=ans
        return and
```

**PS:**
The same program works(i.e gives the right output using **"Run Code" button**) for **n=2,10,20**.
And, I have tried refreshing the page and copy-pasting the correct code in the blank editor (after resetting).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Output Images :**

[image: Buttons present on the bottom right corner]

[image: "Submit" Button]
[image: "Run Code" Button]

Comment: Could be anything. Maybe when you "submit", the same class is used for multiple tests and you are keeping some data in those smelly class variables `t` and `D`.

Comment: @zvone is most likely correct. Move `t` and `D` to be instance attributes

Comment: I'm afraid you're right!! Talk about thinking out of the box. It didn't occur to me that they may use one object to run all test cases. 
Made the changes and guess what - faster than 80% python users :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When leetcode runs your code on their testcases, they run multiple testcases in the same process.

So they do something like this to run your code:

```py
for testcase in testcases:
   sol = Solution()
   assert sol.climbStairs(testcase.input) == testcase.expected
```

This is an issue since you have made `D` a class variable instead of an instance variable. See documentation here for a description of the issue and why it causes problems: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables

> Generally speaking, instance variables are for data unique to each instance and class variables are for attributes and methods shared by all instances of the class:

So each time a Solution instance is created, its `D` is the same object that's already been filled by the instance for the previous test case.

You could solve this by clearing global state in the beginning of `climbStairs`. A better solution would be to define an `__init__` function that sets these instance variables instead of class variables.